# General Solutions to differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What are the steps to finding the general solution of a differential equation?

More specifically how do I solve:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = t^{2}y + e^t$$

Comment: Hey, y is up there on the power or multiplied down ? I mean, is it t^(2y) or t^2 * y ?

Comment: It is the latter.

Comment: This is a linear DE in $y$, have you tried finding the integrating factor?

Comment: One could use the method of integrating factor to solve this equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor.

Comment: the way it was recommended for me was to use a method involving series.

Comment: Answered, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple answer to the first question. Finding the general solution in a closed form of a differential equation cannot always be done (consider $y'=\sin(t^2)$). Rather there are usually steps to finding general solutions of certain classes of differential equations.

This differential equation is a linear differential equation of the form

$\frac{dy}{dt}+p(t)y=q(t)$

where $p(t)=-t^2$ and $q(t)=e^t$.

To solve this class of differential equations we multiply both sides by what is called an integrating factor $\mu(t)=e^{\int p(t) dt}$.

Note then that $e^{\int p(t) dt}\frac{dy}{dt} +e^{\int p(t) dt}\frac{dy}{dt}p(t)y=\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\int p(t) dt}y\right)$. Thus

$$
e^{\int p(t) dt}y=\int q(t) dt.
$$

One can solve from here for $y$. This method can be applied to the differential equation here since is a linear differential equation of the above form.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract $t^2y(t)$ from both sides :

$\frac{dy(t)}{dt} - t^2y(t) = e^t $

Let $ m(t) = e^{\int -t^2y(t)dt} = e^{-\frac{t^3}{3}} $

Then multiply both sides by $m(t)$ and substitute :

$ -e^{-\frac{t^3}{3}}t^2 = \frac{d}{dt}(e^{-\frac{t^3}{3}}) $

Apply the reverse product rule to the left hand side, then integrate and you will get :

$ \int \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{y(t)}{e^{\frac{t^3}{3}}})dt = \int e^{-\frac{t^3}{3}+t}dt $

Evaluating gives :

$\frac{y(t)}{e^{\frac{t^3}{3}}} = \int e^{-\frac{t^3}{3}+t}dt + c $

$c$ is an arbitrary constant of course. Divide both sides by the $m(t)$ we defined earlier and you will get :

$ y(t) = e^{\frac{t^3}{3}}(\int e^{-\frac{t^3}{3}+t}dt + c_1) $

Comment: I've given the complete answer, check it out. Also, when you find the answer that suits you make sure to vote up and most importantly confirm it, so that other people will not lose time by giving new identical answers